# How to clone a React Component (to append somewhere else) using React.js instead of JQuery.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, backbone.js, reactjs

I am working on some fieldsets using React.js + Backbone.js.

I have a table containing many columns and rows. Task is to make first column fixed whenever number of columns are greater than to show on screen. (e.g total columns are 8, only 6 columns can be shown on screen) So other two can be seen by scrolling horizontally.

With the logic currently I am is, use jQuery to clone each first column of each row, and create a new table, then append it after the original table, use CSS to position it on the original table, so the user can see the first column is fixed.

I am not satisfy with this approach, need your help to do great with great Virtual DOM of great Reactjs :) Any idea, suggestion will be appreciable :)

Comment: React components should be reusable, so can you just render it twice?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can just do that with CSS, depending on required browser support.

Comment: @Douglas thanks for the reply, if i render it twice, how can it be possible to edit on first one and get done on second one ? does React allow these sort of events, like JQuery.clone()?
also i don't need to render whole table instead i want only first columns, i think which is possible through refs. please help :)

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand thanks for the reply. if that's possible what can be better than this. it should work on all great browsers but if not, at least i0S compatibility is must. please help :)

Comment: Hi, what sort of events do you have in mind? If the idea is to share the data between the two renderings, then just put the data somewhere common, then render both based on the same data. Good presentation about how this can work here: http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/08/03/community-roundup-21.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start with simple react Table component:

```
var Table= React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <table>
            {this.props.data.map(function(row){
                return <tr>
                    {row.map(function(cell){
                        return <td> {cell} </td>
                    })}
                </tr>
            })}
        </table>;
    }
});
```

this components is just a demo, real life table should be more complex.

now, the table you want is this component:

```
var DubbledTable= React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var firstColumn= 
            this.props.data.map(function(row){
                return [row[0]]
            })
        return <span>
            <Table data={firstColumn} />
            <Table data={this.props.data} />
        </span>
    }
})
```

demo- http://jsfiddle.net/psx9f644/

enjoy

Comment: Thanks yarden, that was helpful.